# Trying to instance a UILabel when instancing a UISwitcher

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, uiswitch

I'm creating a simple code that allows me to instance a UILabel aside of a UISwitcher.
The switcher is being created normally and I create a "UIRadio" class to properly instance the label right on the start.

Heres the .m:

```
#import "UIRadio.h"

@implementation UIRadio

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithLabel:(CGRect)frame Label:(NSString*)labelText
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.frame=frame;
        label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100)];
        label.text=labelText;
        [self.superview addSubview:label];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)removeFromSuperview{
    [label removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

And here is the .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIRadio : UISwitch{
    UILabel *label;
}

- (id)initWithLabel:(CGRect)frame Label:(NSString*)label;
@end
```

It appears the UILabel is being created correctly, but it doesn't show on the view.
Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just creating the radio but when you initiate, you wouldn't have the superview, because you didn't add it to any view. so you can do like this below

**After you add that radio view to another view by addSubView: method only it will have reference to superview.**

If you want to add label to switch then you could add like this

```
  [aSwitch addSubview:label];
```

Because UISwitch also a UIView

```
  UIView--->UIControl--->UISwitch--->UIRadio



-(id)initWithLabel:(CGRect)frame Label:(NSString*)labelText andSuperView:(UIView*)aSuperView
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.frame=frame;
        label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100)];
        label.text=labelText;
        [aSuperView addSubview:label];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Oh! Worked! Thanks <3

Answer (score 2):

I bet `self.superview` is nil when you call `addSubview` in your `initWithLabel` method.

I think you're going to have a hard time adding the label this way.  The problem is that when you instantiate `UIRadio` and initialize it with `initWithLabel:Label:` (which, by the way, is a very weird signature, did you mean `initWithFrame:label:`?) the instance of `UIRadio` does not yet have a superview.  You create the label, as you say, but there is no superview (yet) so your attempt to add that label to the view hierarchy fails.

I suggest that you create a separate subclass of `UIView` that will *contain* both a `UISwitch` and a label.  Then you can instantiate that class and its init method can create both a switch and a label, and add those controls to itself as subviews.  You might try something like this:

```
@interface LabeledSwitch : UIView
@end

@implementation LabeledSwitch {
    UISwitch *_switch;
    UILabel *_label;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame labelText:(NSString *)labelText {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _switch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _label.text = labelText;
        [self addSubview:_switch];
        [self addSubview:_label];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    // Whatever code you like to set reasonable frames
    // for _switch and _label based on the current bounds
    // of this container view.
}

@end
```

Comment: Hm, I've tried to NSLog the name of the class "self.superview" is calling and it just don't output anything. In case its really nil, how do I get the parent view?